# How to save long form-data when disconnected from internet in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently building a Laravel app that the user will access from their mobile device when in the 'field'. Users will be performing an inspection, and will need to complete a long form in the app (website).

I know that in some cases the user may loose internet connection while completing the form.

My question is, how do I ensure that the filled form data is not lost in the event that the internet is lost or if the page refreshes, etc?

Before I was building this on Laravel I had each input save to local storage using jQuery, and it seemed to work how I needed it to.

I'm just interested in know if the local storage method is best, or maybe if Laravel offers a different method I'm unaware of for this case.

Thanks!

Comment: It's something to deal with on the client-side, do you use a framework on the client side (like Vue etc.)? you might find some plugin/package that can help out with keeping data in localStorage

Comment: I cannot format the comment, so I wrote an answer below, and it was modified and formatted. You can read it now. It will answer your question with a different idea than saving data in the client side.

Comment: If there's no internet then presumably they can't even load the form to begin with right? Maybe making an app (native or PWA) is necessary for your use case to have something that is loadable even without internet and that can wait for internet connection

Answer (score -1):

The `localStorage` is not the best option as it can also be Deleted if the user clears the browser history
He can not access this data from any other browser or device

If you are using `SPA` framework like `vue` or `react` etc... you can move data to server permanently using `axios`
And if you use `jQuery`
You can transfer data using `AJAX`

With the addition of a database field called `is_publish`
of type `boolean`
0 `false` means **draft**
1 `true` means **publish**

note: This solution is used when there is a multi-step form to add a product or add a service such as upwork and similar sites